# Is there is any way to add Lazy Loading for video tag with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

At the moment, I am working on a project that requires me to add three videos to the homepage, but loading them all at once will reduce the load time considerably.

Also i want to use `<video/>` tag instead of using `<iframe/>` because i want that autoplay functionality.
What's the best way to do this in React? Using NextJS and Chakra UI.

Comment: Do you have to scroll down to see them?

Comment: yes, i want them to load when i reach to that section where they are present

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) and do it as below. For React all you have to do is to add the below code in an `useEffect` with empty dependency.

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");

function handleIntersection(entries) {
  entries.map(async (entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      const res = await fetch("/video.mp4");
      const data = await res.blob();
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
    }
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);
observer.observe(video);
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline></video>
```

Also I used a video with a relative path to avoid possible [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS) issues.

Answer (score 1):

i found a way to do it using '[@react-hook/intersection-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/intersection-observer)'

```
import useIntersectionObserver from '@react-hook/intersection-observer'
import { useRef } from 'react'

const LazyIframe = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef()
  const lockRef = useRef(false)
  const { isIntersecting } = useIntersectionObserver(containerRef)
  if (isIntersecting) {
    lockRef.current = true
  }
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      {lockRef.current && (
        <video
          src={"add video source here"}
          type="video/mp4"
        ></video>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```